# Improve the performance of this query (SQL-SERVER)

Tags: sql-server, select, sum

I don't know what else can I do to  improve the speed of this query. I have created non-clustered index but the result is the same. I have a lot of data and Azure is giving me some DTU problems.

What Index would you recommend?

```
SELECT 
    SUM(t.total_amount) as SumaAmount,
        COUNT(t.id) as TotalTransaccions
FROM 
    rtv_turnover_transaction as t 
    INNER JOIN tills as till ON till.ID=t.till_id
    INNER JOIN rtv_trans_articles as ta ON t.transaction_id=ta.transaction_id
    INNER JOIN articles as art ON art.id=ta.article_id
    INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id=art.group_a_id
    INNER JOIN Clients as s ON s.id=t.cliente_id
    INNER JOIN rtv_transactions as tr ON tr.id=t.transaction_id
    INNER JOIN Ubicacion as u ON t.ubicacio_id=u.id 
    INNER JOIN Operadores as o ON t.operador_id=o.ID
where 
    tr.card_num IS NULL 
    and t.trans_date >= '2018-08-01' and t.trans_date >= '2018-09-01'
```

Hope you can help me. I am newbie with databases.

Comment: What index(es) do you have (both `CLUSTERED` and `NONCLUSTERED`)? Please include their DDL too.

Comment: Could you upload an actual execution plan to this site?  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: It would help to give us the output of your query plan: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan

Comment: You may want to check your WHERE clause:  `and t.trans_date >= '2018-08-01' and t.trans_date >= '2018-09-01'`

Comment: I doubt between is quicker in execution. It evaluates to two inequalities. It's more handy, though.

Comment: Why do you need all these joins? Get rid of the ones that serve no useful purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@talendguy,first tell us your requirement.Wht is the need to join so many table only to get count and sum from one table.

Revise carefully are those each table require.

From your query it appear that, most of the tables are related to `rtv_turnover_transaction`.

Create non clustered index on all those columns of rtv_turnover_transaction which are use in join condition.

You can leave those columns which belong to small table.

If still your query is slow then Define  `PK-FK relationship` and `Trusted Check` constraint.

This way no need of creating so many index.`Trusted relationship` help optimiser

> When primary and foreign keys are defined as constraints in the
>   database schema, the server can use that information to create optimal
>   execution plans.

[Further Reading](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/11/t-sql-queries/benefits-indexing-foreign-keys)

create separate `Non Clustered Index on trans_date`

In table `rtv_transactions` create non clustered index on `card_num`

Also if `READ UNCOMMITTED` Data is not a problem or there is no chance of `READ UNCOMMITTED` Data then you can safely use `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint in all table.

```
rtv_turnover_transaction WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Note : I am not telling you to blindly use `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint, but if circumstances allow you then it is very performant.

You can read `Benefit and Limitation of Nolock`.

Comment: I think where clause is typo mistake

Comment: How does a FK negate the need for indexing? That is wrong. And why are you suggesting they use NOLOCK? That is simply bad advice, especially for a system that appears to be dealing with money of some sort. That hint is NOT performance tool that doesn't have cost. It can and will randomly return missing and/or duplicate rows along with a host of other "features". https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I will reply about FK negate the need of indexing later ,because explanation need time.I never said to use WITH (NOLOCK) straight away.Read my statement carefully .Nolock is not always bad, in some scenario it can be very safely use.

Comment: NOLOCK can be useful **very** occasionally. And never when you care about the accuracy of the results. You suggested using that and didn't offer any warnings about how bad it can be. And the indexing thing as posted is simply wrong. Maybe a language barrier but the way it reads is incorrect.